# ¿Por qué no funciona el Scanner dentro del primer case del switch pero sí en el segundo?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-util-scanner, ant

Estoy intentando crear una "pausa" con `op = in.nextLine();` en el código para evitar intercambiar abruptamente entre un `case x:` y `public void Run()`

**Mi problema es que no sé porque en el `case c:` NO funciona el `op = in.nextLine();`, pero en el `case f:` SÍ funciona**

¿Me podrían explicar por favor que estoy haciendo mal?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Boyle extends EMain {

    @Override
    public void Run() {
        System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
        System.out.flush();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //Objects and Vars
        float p1, v1, p2, v2;
        String op, classn = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

        //Output
        System.out.println(
                "-------"
                + "\n Boyle "
                + "\n-------");

        //MMenu
        System.out.println("""
                           Select an option:
                           (c)alculate
                           (f)orm
                           e(x)it to Main menu""");

        op = in.nextLine();
        in.nextLine();

        //Functions
        switch (op) {
            case "c":
                System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
                System.out.flush();
                //Input
                System.out.println("Pressure 1 (P1): ");
                p1 = in.nextFloat();

                System.out.println("Volume 1 (V1): ");
                v1 = in.nextFloat();

                System.out.println("Pressure 2 (P2): ");
                p2 = in.nextFloat();

                System.out.println("Volume 2 (V2): ");
                v2 = in.nextFloat();

                //Functions
                if (p1 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("(!) P1 is missing");
                    p1 = (p2 * v2) / v1;
                    System.out.println("P1 = " + p1);
                    System.out.println("\nUsed Formula: p1 = (p2 * v2) / v1");
                } else if (v1 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("(!) V1 is missing");
                    v1 = (p2 * v2) / p1;
                    System.out.println("V1 = " + v1);
                    System.out.println("\nUsed Formula: v1 = (p2 * v2) / p1");
                } else if (p2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("(!) P2 is missing");
                    p2 = (p1 * v1) / v2;
                    System.out.println("P2 = " + p2);
                    System.out.println("\nUsed Formula: p2 = (p1 * v1) / v2");
                } else if (v2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("(!) V2 is missing");
                    v2 = (p1 * v1) / p2;
                    System.out.println("V2 = " + v2);
                    System.out.println("\nUsed Formula: v2 = (p1 * v1) / p2");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("ERROR (!): No empty target variable");
                }

                System.out.println("Press enter to exit");
                op = in.nextLine();
                this.Run();
                break;
            case "f":
                System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
                System.out.flush();

                System.out.println("All \"" + classn + "\" formulas\n\n"
                        + "p1 = (p2 * v2) / v1\n"
                        + "v1 = (p2 * v2) / p1\n"
                        + "p2 = (p1 * v1) / v2\n"
                        + "v2 = (p1 * v1) / p2\n\n"
                        + "Press enter to quit");
                op = in.nextLine();
                this.Run();
                break;
            case "x":
                Main.main(null);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *no funciona*? ¿Qué debería hacer y qué hace? ¿Has depurado tu código? ¿Qué observas en tu depuración?

Comment: @A.Cedano En el ```case f``` espera a una entrada del usuario, no importa si se guarda o no, el objetivo es que funciona como una pausa del programa. El problema es que tal como funciona en el ```case f``` debería de funcionar en el ```case c```

Comment: En lugar de esperar la entrada del usuario ```op = in.nextLine();``` se la salta

Comment: En esta parte ```System.out.println("Press enter to exit");
                op = in.nextLine();
                this.Run();
                break;```

Answer (score 0):

Se debe poner `in.nextLine();`dos veces para hacer que el Scanner lea el salto de linea (`\n`)

Basado en: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

En esta parte de tu código estas capturando el valor ingresado pero le estas dando un salto con la segunda linea de código

```
op = in.nextLine();   //captura el valor ingresado usando Scanner
        in.nextLine();//nuevo uso de Scanner...esta demas..
```

si quieres hacer una pausa,te comparto un método que cree para ese uso,espero te ayude..saludos

```
public static void Pausa(){
        String seguir;
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nPresiona Enter para continuar...");
        try{
            seguir = teclado.nextLine();}
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
```